# Default value in clojure maps

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have a clojure map. Name it `opts`. I know 2 ways to get values from this map such that if there is no key get some default value:

```
(let [opts {}
      title-1 (or (:title opts) "Default title")
      title-2 (:title opts "Default title")]
  (println title-1 title-2))
```

I saw some libraries (quil, incanter) use first approach with `or`. It seems to me that second approach is more concise and cleaner. Is there advantages in the first approach?
Disadvantage of using `(or (:title opts) "Default value")` is that we cannot pass `false` and `nil` as values anymore, default value is always used in this case.

Comment: You can also use `(get opts :title "Default title")`.

Comment: @ponzao Which might be even better because `get` will not throw `NullPointerException` if map is `nil`. It will either return `nil` or the default value if it was specified.

Comment: @IvanKoblik `(:title nil "Default")` also works fine.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov You're right, I was thinking of this case `opts :title "Default"` that also works but will throw NPE if opts is `nil`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A crucial difference between `(or (:key hash) default)` and `(:key hash default)` is the fact that the former evaluates `default` only if it is necessary. In the latter case it is always evaluated. Therefore you should use `or` if an evaluation of `default` is expensive.

Another difference becomes apparent when your hash contains values which are false in a boolean context. In cases of such values `(or (:key hash) default)` will be evaluated to `default` instead of `false` or `nil` which you expect. In contrast to the `or` expression, `(:key hash default)` will yield correct results. As a side note, think twice before storing `nil` as values in a hash.

Fine, those were the important differences. Now let's move to minor ones.

```
(or (:title opts) "Default title")
```

is expanded by the reader to

```
;; Redacted for the sake of brevity.
(let* [x (:title opts)]
  (if x
    x
    "Default title"))
```

Arguably, it is less efficient than to simply evaluate

```
(:title opts "Default title")
```

Of course without any benchmarks it is hard to estimate the difference is speed, however I believe that it should be marginal.

On the other hand, at first glance `(or (:key hash) :default)` seems to be easier to understand for someone not used to the `(:key hash :default)` idiom. Consider programmers coming from other languages. In Ruby for instance the typical approach to handling a non existant element of a hash is

```
val = hash[:key] || :default
```

Hence, the first expression might be easier to parse by humans not accustomed to certain Clojure's idioms.

Comment: I totally disagree that you should be consistent throughout: each style is occasionally necessary. You should use `or` style if the default expression is very expensive to calculate, or get-with-default when `nil` or `false` are valid values, and you need to distinguish between "Nothing there" and "false or nil there".

Comment: @amalloy, thanks for the comment and pointing out important differences. I've revised the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `:or` key is used for when map destructuting.

```
(defn f [{:keys [title-1 title-2] :as opts
          :or {title-1 "default-1" title-2 "default-2"}}]
  (println opts)
  (println title-1)
  (println title-2))
```

which gives you

```
> (f {})
{}
default-1
default-2
nil

> (f {:title-1 "foo"})
{:title-1 foo}
foo
default-2
nil

> (f {:title-2 "bar"})
{:title-2 bar}
default-1
bar
nil

> (f {:title-1 "foo" :title-2 "bar"})
{:title-1 foo, :title-2 bar}
foo
bar
nil
```